# Define distance between different areas in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have an Anylogic model where there are different storage areas (using Pallet racks) and waiting areas defined using rectangles. I want define distance between all these areas. Is there any way to do so in Analogic? Perhaps, by defining 1 small square in the model equals x meters or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the distance in pixels between 2 areas you can do this:

```
double distInPixels=node1.getCenter().distance(node2.getCenter());
```

if you want the distance in meters, you can use the scale object as follows

```
double distInMeters=scale.toLengthUnits(distInPixels,METER);
```

Check the help documentation for distance units if you don't like meters.

the scale allows you to change pixels to meters:
[image]

Comment: Hello Felipe, your answer helps but I wish to set the distance between two areas. For ex, pixel distance between two areas is 10 pixels. I want to set 1 pixel=2 meters such that dist. between those areas be 10*2 = 20 meters. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: look for the scale object... there are 2 objects that exist when you create a new model, one of them is the scale... do you know the scale at all?

Comment: No, I do not. Can I find it in Main properties?

Comment: i updated the answer so you can see what the scale is... it's visible in the projects/main/presentation